# Mouse resolution changes when connecting second screen

Tags: touchpad, display-resolution, xinput, multiple-monitors, mouse-pointer

**Issue**

My 16.04 laptop has a 1366x768 display and all is perfect.
When i connect an external display (1920x1200) all is perfect but the mouse *sensitivity* (may i call it *resolution* or *precision*).
Cursor "jumps" between pixels while moving slowly and i found difficult to point small areas.
In other words: **pointer loose precision**.
This happen using both mouse or touchpad.

I've seen the same issue ("pixel jump") on another 16.04 PC with another mouse and a single hi-res display (1920x1080), so i guess this is a "feature" that occurs with hi-res displays.

**What i tried #1**

`xset -q|grep accel` outputs `acceleration:  5/1    threshold:  5`

Hacking around with xset parameters i found that `xset -m 1 5` works a little better but doesn't solve the "precision" issue at all (still jumping pixels).

**What i tried #2**

I tried to look for `xinput` parameter changes while plugging the external display: `xinput list` outputs a lot of devices, then i tested them using: `xinput list-props`.

The only one that changes when connecting the second display is:

```
xinput list-props "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer"
```

and the only parameter that changes is:

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144):
1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

to

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144):
0.415703, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.640000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

**Questions**

1. Can i prevent this to happen?
2. Can i modify `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` parameter with xinput?
3. Is it possible to have different pointer behaviour for different display resolutions at the same time? i mean: "fast" for hi-res, "smooth" for low-res?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question after 2 mounths, i approached again the issue and i found a solution.

`xinput --list --short` outputs two drivers related to touchpad:

`Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer             id=11` and
`ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                   id=14`

The only one that changes when connecting the external monitor is the `id=11`.
Changing back its parameters using `xinput set-prop 11 144 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1` (144 is the Coordinate Transformation Matrix prop) didn't change the cursor behaviour, then i tried hacking with the other driver and succeeded:

```
xinput set-prop 14 144 .5 0 0 0 .5 0 0 0 1
xinput set-prop 14 273 25
```

this way i have been able to increment the cursor precision when moving slowly (through the Coordinate Transformation Matrix, prop 144) and keep an high acceleration when moving my fingers faster on the pad (Device Accel Velocity Scaling, prop 273).

I think this info may be useful for other full-HD owners too.